# Empty column on table using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm using Bootstrap on a table and an empty column adds itself on the right (cf screenshot). That's weird especially since I use it for another table and all is fine with it... but this one decided to do what it want ^^

Here's table HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive" style="text-align: center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>{% trans "Issue type" %}</th>
        <th>{% trans "State" %}</th>
        <th>{% trans "Date" %}</th>
        <th>{% trans "New comment" %}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  {% if issues|length == 0 %}
  <tr class="empty-row">
    <td class="no-issue" colspan="3">{% trans "none(f)" %}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endif %}
  {% for issue in issues %}
  <tr class="issue">
    <td><a href="{% url 'customer_support:comment_issue' issue.id %}">
        {% if issue.issue_type %}{{ issue.issue_type }}{% else %}{{ issue.other }}{% endif %}
    </a></td>
    <td>{% if issue.resolved %}
            <span class="badge badge-success">{{ issue.get_state_display }}</span>
        {% else %}
            <span class="badge badge-warning">{{ issue.get_state_display }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
    <td>{{ issue.date | date }}</td>
    <td>{% if issue.has_notifications %}
            <span class="badge badge-warning">{% trans 'New' %}</span>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And the screenshot and the empty column on the right:

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: You have four column headers but only 3 body columns. HTML takes the largest number to render the whole table.

Comment: Oh non I'm confused, sorry. I was talking about the column on the right of "Nouveau commentaire" because it's normal that this one is empty. I update the question for you to understand :)

Comment: And I know that it is display: block from table-responsive of Bootstrap but on my other table there's not this "column" too much. I'd like to know how can I fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little digging I found the answer [in the Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#responsive-tables) (emphasis mine):

> Responsive tables allow tables to be scrolled horizontally with ease. Make any table responsive across all viewports by **wrapping** a `.table` with `.table-responsive`.

Your example used `.table-responsive` on the `<table>` itself, rather than on a wrapper element:

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="text-align: center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Issue type</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>New comment</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="issue">
        <td><a href="#">Autre</a></td>
        <td><span class="badge badge-warning">En cours</span></td>
        <td>6 December 2018</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh God thank you it works !!! I probably have a bad search because I didn't find anything !! Thanks again :D